# Average the smallest 3 values of the last 5 values, excluding blank cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to average the smallest 3 values of the last 5 valves, excluding blank cells, in a row.
I have a working Excel formula, but I'm not savvy with Sheets yet.
Here is a screen shot of my Excel sheet.
Excel formula: {=IFERROR(AVERAGE(SMALL(INDEX(2:2,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(D2:CL2)/(D2:CL2<>""),5)):CL2,{1,2,3})),"")}

[image: Averages]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

To get the last five values in each row, use `sortn()`. To get the three smallest values among those five, use, `query()`, like this:

```
=average( 
  query( 
    sortn( transpose(K2:2), 5, 0, transpose(column(K2:2) * not(isblank(K2:2))), false ), 
    "order by Col1 limit 3", 0 
  ) 
)
```

To show a blank when there are less than five values in a row, use `count()` and `if()`, like this:

```
=if( 
  count(K2:2) < 5, 
  iferror(1/0), 
  average( 
    query( 
      sortn( transpose(K2:2), 5, 0, transpose(column(K2:2) * not(isblank(K2:2))), false ), 
      "order by Col1 limit 3", 0 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: It works perfectly if there is 5 or more values, but if there is only 3 values, it gives a false answer. I would like it to be blank if there is less than 5 values.   Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Making an exception this time because it is your first question. Edited the answer.

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)